# Rascal: What does @Category Do?

Tags: rascal

Please can anyone help me explain the meaning of the Rascal Grammar definitions.

```
 syntax Result 
         = aliassed: Expr!obj!lst expr "as" Id attr 
         | normal: Expr expr ;`

    syntax Expr
       = attr: VId var "." {Id "."}+ attrs
       | var: VId var
       | placeHolder: PlaceHolder
       | key: VId var "." "@id"
       | @category="Number" \int: Int intValue
       | @category="Constant" \str: Str strValue
       | @category="Number" \real: Real realValue
       | @category="Constant" \dt: DateTime dtValue
       | @category="Constant" point: Point pointValue
       | @category="Constant" polygon: Polygon polygonValue;
```

What does `aliassed: Expr!obj!lst expr "as" Id attr` mean?
What does the "!" do in this context?
I understand that @category defines some kind of logical grouping but of what practical use is this?

Answer (score 0):

- `@category` has *no* meaning for the parser generation. It tags a rule (and so a also a tree node) with a scope name that is used for *syntax highlighting* later. So `@category="Number"` means that the characters recognized with it will get the style associated with the scope `Number`
- `Expr!obj!lst` means that any `Expr` is allowed at that position in the rule, except the Expr rule labeled `obj` or the Expr rule labeled `lst`. It is a [disambiguation](https://www.rascal-mpl.org/docs/Rascal/Declarations/SyntaxDefinition/Disambiguation/) construct

More information about syntax definitions in general in Rascal can be found here: https://www.rascal-mpl.org/docs/Rascal/Declarations/SyntaxDefinition/